# Adjusting the number of results for Windows start-menu search

Tags: windows-7, search, start-menu

When searching in the start menu search in Windows 7, results often appear categorised.
Can the maximum number of results per category can be changed?

To clarify with a screenshot, under the heading **--programs (4)--**, I get only 3 of the 4 results. Can this maximum-results value that stands on 3 be changed?

Further than that, can a category be excluded (for example, not to get the "control panel" results that you can see in the screenshot).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open Control Panel -> Indexing Options -> Advanced -> and under the file types tab, deselect the .cpl extension:

[image: Control panel 'Indexing Options']

[image: 'Advanced Options' of control panel 'Indexing Options']

I don't know how you would do the "Max Results" part of your question.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that and now it's re-indexing, we'll see how it goes. In the mean time it actually gave some clue to the "max" issue, while re-indexing I got incomplete results (less results -> free space) and then it shows more then just the 3. So it seems its rather dynamic in using the space it has, unfortunately it probably means that it cannot be changed.

Comment: Well, indexing is complete and the control-panel section is still shown, the items there are not the control-panel items themselves, but pages from the control panel. For example, search-keyword "history" results in "delete browsing history" (from the Internet Options item in control panel") under that category. So it would seem those pages are not .cpl and are still shown.